# Inserting a new column with certain values printed by a loop

Tags: python, pandas

```
for i,j in zip(data['Min7day'],data['close_price']):
    if i > j:
        data['New'] = 'Flat'
    else
        data['New'] = 'List'
```

I'm trying to insert a new column with a certain string when the condition is True.
What happens is that instead of writing each row with the 'Flat or 'List' string , i get the same value in every single row. I get every row with 'Flat'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: could you post an excerpt of your data columns `Min7day` and `close_price` so the problem can be reproduced?

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.where`

**Ex:**

```
data['New'] = np.where(data['Min7day'] > data['close_price'], 'Flat', 'List')
```